# javascript- replace text with part of the file name

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I'm trying to create a script in adobe illustrator that will check if a file name contains "ph" +5 numbers.
If it has been found then it will replace a part of a text with the match from the file name.

This is what I have so far I just can't get it to work, the text is replaced with "null"

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;

var name = doc.name;
var match = name.match(/ph\d{5}/);

for (i = 0; i < doc.textFrames.length; i++)
{
    doc.textFrames[i].contents = doc.textFrames[i].contents.replace(/ph00000/gi, match);
}
```

Comment: I'd advice don't use the name `name` in Illustrator scripts. Illustrator's API has pretty much bugs and a variable with name `name` often contains 'Adobe Illustrator' string instead of whatever you put into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try this:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;

var match = doc.name.match(/ph\d{5}/);

if (match != null) {
  for (i = 0; i < doc.textFrames.length; i++) {
    doc.textFrames[i].contents = doc.textFrames[i].contents.replace(/ph00000/gi, match[0]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can encapsulate the text that you want to replace with group constructs, and since you're using [String.prototype.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), you can capture the parenthesized group and pass the callback function as the 2nd argument in your `.replace` function.

[image: regex replace table]

Read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter)

Example:

```js
const textString = "This is ph54321 or ph12345";

const newString1 = textString.replace(/(ph)\d{5}/gi, function (matches, p1) {
    return p1 + "appended"; // "This is phappended or phappended"
});

const newString2 = textString.replace(/ph(\d{5})/gi, function (matches, p1) {
    return "BIGPH" + p1; // "This is BIGPH54321 or BIGPH12345"
});

console.log({newString1});
console.log({newString2});
```

Comment: Alas, Adobe Illustratror has no arrow functions. It would be nice if you rewrite it for Extendscript (~ES3).